# Is there any tax in India for money from Saudi Arabia

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, money-transfer, saudi-arabia

I work in Saudi Arabia, I took a loan here, nearly 10 lakhs Indian Rupees (1,000,000 Indian Rupees) and already transferred to my NRE account in India.

My questions are:

1. Is this amount taxable in India? If yes then how much I have to pay
   as tax.(I had heard that money from Gulf is non taxable in India, Is
   there any form or document I have to submit to bank to avoid tax?)
2. How to fixed Deposit this money from Saudi Arabia or from India
   through my husband or parents?
3. If I put this money in 2-3 FD's (like 5 lakh one FD and 2 or 3 lakh
   other FD's) then the interest earned is taxable? Can I withdraw any
   FD without maturity if needed in urgent?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are NRI, any income you earn is not taxable in India whether you transfer to India or not.

> Is this amount taxable in India? If yes then how much I have to pay as tax.

No it is not taxable.

> How to fixed Deposit this money from Saudi Arabia or from India through my husband or parents?

You can open Fixed Deposits in your name or your husband/parents name. It is your choice. Some Banks allow you to operate an NRE account via Internet

> If I put this money in 2-3 FD's (like 5 lakh one FD and 2 or 3 lakh other FD's) then the interest earned is taxable?

Interest is taxable.

> Can I withdraw any FD without maturity if needed in urgent?

That depends on type of FD you have opened. Some allow withdrawal before maturity with a penalty other don't allow.